# NginX not executing PHP

Tags: php, nginx, ubuntu-14.04

I've been through dozens of potential solutions to this problem but cannot find anything that works. Basically, PHP files are not executing on my NginX + PHP_fpm + Ubuntu 14 server. I have all the packages, and they are running. I've cleared browser cache etc., but nothing has worked yet. I appreciate all the help!

As of right now, if I try accessing the PHP file, the GET will return it as an HTML file but will not execute the script.

Here is my nginx.conf file:

```
worker_processes 1;
worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;

events {
 worker_connections  3000;
}

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

http {
   include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
   #default_type  application/octet-stream;
   default_type text/html;

   log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                     '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                     '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

   access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

   sendfile        on;
   #tcp_nopush     on;

   keepalive_timeout  65;

   #gzip  on;

   include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
   include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Here is my /sites-available/default file:

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
      error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
      location = /50x.html {
              root /usr/share/nginx/html;
      }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

        # With php5-cgi alone:
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        # With php5-fpm:
        #fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        #fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny all;
    #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#    listen 80;
#    listen [::]:80;
#
#    server_name example.com;
#
#    root /var/www/example.com;
#    index index.html;
#
#    location / {
#        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#    }
#}
```

Here is my server conf file:

```
server {

   listen 8000 default_server;

   listen [::]:8000 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/html;
    #index index.php index.html index.htm;

   #location / {

     #index index.php index.html index.htm;

   #}
}
```

As you can see, I've been playing around with these files. But to no avail.

Comment: What does your error log (/var/log/nginx/error.log) say?  You may want to grep cgi /var/log/nginx/error.log and see what pops out.  I bet you'll find your answer in there.

Comment: Nothing enters the error log when I try to load a php file.

Comment: What's the URL you're requesting?

Comment: localhost:8000/info.php

Comment: There is no `~ \.php$` location block for the server listening on port 8000. You need to add it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, so based on our comments back and forth you need to add this section to your nginx config for the server config listening on :8000.

That regex tells nginx that whenever it gets a request for a URL with a file ending in .php to send that to the fastcgi process.  Otherwise it's going to default to returning the raw file that matches in /var/www/html.

Hope that helps.

```
# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

    # With php5-cgi alone:
    #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    # With php5-fpm:
    #fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    #fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: worked! thank you! They key was that the location block in default was not executing. So moving it to the actual config file fixed it.

Comment: I can not execute `.php` file.

Comment: I found that the default 

`location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    } `
Was giving me trouble - If I comment this whole block out, so it falls through to the `location ~ \.php${...}` block, everything works

Answer (score 1):

Just add the below code to your given location with PHP version you have installed on the server.

> /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}
```